# Erro ao tentar observar o conteúdo de uma variável ou propriedade de um objeto no debugger do VS 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, visual-studio, debug

Em praticamente todas as vezes que tento *observar* o conteúdo de uma variável ou propriedade de um objeto, recebo o erro abaixo:

> Function evaluation disabled because a previous function evaluation timed out. You must continue execution to reenable function evaluation.

Isso não acontecia no VS210 e nem no VS2012, pelo menos não até o ultimo patch de atualizações.

A pergunta é. Existe alguma configuração, ou definição de aplicação para que o Watcher do Debugger volte a funcionar corretamente?

Answer (score 2):

Eu tive a oportunidade de experimentar este aviso no VS2010 também. Na verdade, ele pode aparecer sempre que o conteúdo que você estiver inspecionando tomar muito tempo para sofrer `Eval`.

Para fins de debugging, `Eval` equivale ao sequestro da thread observada pelo debugger, que então permite que você não apenas tenha acesso ao conteúdo da thread mas também a manipule (por exemplo rodando código diretamente na Debug CLI).

O problema principal dessa técnica é que, para poder congelar o estado da aplicação, o debugger pára todas as outras threads. O problema óbvio ocorre se a thread observada tenta interagir com alguma das threads congeladas.

Se este é o seu caso, a resolução do seu problema vai depender da maneira como seu código foi implementado.

Comment: Faz sentido agora. Visto que normalmente ocorre num trecho de código assíncrono.

Comment: Exato. Isso também pode acontecer se uma das threads congeladas está consumindo um objeto em *SyncLock*, e a thread principal tenta fazê-lo durante debugging.